# SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflow - Let user select approver

Tags: designer-workflow

I am facing a requirement where a user should select the approver. There is no pre configured list.

The user clicks a button in a custom page, then another page has to load where user selects approvers and clicks submit. This has to lead to system sending mail to approver and update item status.

The catch is, no custom workflow using Visual Studio is allowed, i.e no server side deployments allowed.
All this needs to be done using Designer based SharePoint.

Since all my experience is list initiated simple workflows, I am not sure if this is possible with the catch mentioned above.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a List Workflow in SharePoint Designer. And modify the initiation form and add parameters. Then use these parameters in your workflow.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-workflow-initiation-form-26879578-a62b-4fef-8b7e-9e4400afc94b

Comment: Thanks @Amal :)

After a day's reasearch I have the same thought. For all who are going to visit this question, following is what I am planning to to do.

1. Create SharePoint Hosted App
2. Add Workflow with parameter inputs, Custom Outcome Site Column & Choices
3. Add Workflow initiation form with people picker which can pass the parameters to workflow and allow user to specify the approvers as well as choose different outcome
4. Deploy

Answer (score 2):

You can also capture the approver names in the list form (new / edit) using Person or group field. Then read the names in SharePoint designer workflow for sending the mail

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that's approach I took. Checkout the comment above.